# Process address space and PTE's User/Kernel bit

Tags: process, arm, cpu-architecture, mmu

Most of modern processors implement paging (for memory management) and in their paging PTEs (Page Table Entry) are very often including user/kernel bit for restrict unwanted access. Why this bottleneck? Is there any reason why don't do it this way:

Process address space is divided on user and kernel space, of course. And exactly that is the direct reason for implement two PTPRs (Page Table Pointer Register) as we can see on ARM. Simple logic on HW level then can divide logical address to user and kernel space. Now, both modes have its own page table entries except which we want to share (I assume we wouldn't share pages that we want their access will be restricted only to kernel). So, there is no reason to implement user/kernel bit, isn't it so? Am I missing something?

Comment: Out of interest, in what way do you think one particular PTE bit would be a "bottleneck"? Note that permissions on ARM have long been finer-grained than a single privileged/unprivileged bit anyway. Also note that the hardware division of VA space into two separate page tables only came in in ARMv6, at which point there already existed 20-odd years worth of legacy software...

Comment: @Notlikethat Thank you for your answer. As far as I know in PTE on ARM are all modes assorted to privileged and unprivileged mode. The only one unprivileged mode is user mode. Moment, two page tables aren't used anymore? Sorry, maybe it's my English too bad to understand your comment.